# Set break point and debug the source code in third party API

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a third party API in the project. I have no source code but I want to go to it to set break points.
I had RedGate .NET Reflector trial edition but it had expired.

Is there a free tools?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Because I got exception and I wanted to know the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you have is a DLL then you should be able to decompile it with [Dot Peek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (which is free) and take a look.

However, if what you call a third party API is a remote method of some sort (webservice, rest service, etc) then you will not be able to look at it since you do not have the compiled DLLs and this seems more like a problem in their side and not at yours.

Comment: The API was wrote by Service Stack, which is a sort of rest service. So no way?

Comment: When you say "by" do you mean "with"? It really doesn't matter who wrote it, but by what you say we can infer that it was using Service Stack which is a framework for creating web services. How do you call it? If you use some sort of remote client than it is a web service and you won't be able to decompile/debug it. Your best shot is to get in touch with whoever is responsible for keeping it.

Comment: It was wrote with ServiceStack, then in my code I consumed it via code  NewMessage = client.Put(request); AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient client = new AuthenticatedJsonServiceClient("http://blah.blah.com/MessageService/api/");By the way, I can browser the API from object browser to look at the properties.

Comment: Dot Peek can display the source code but can not step in it.

Comment: If it can display the source code of the service then what you have is a DLL and not a remote call. When you decompile something in DotPeek you can use it to EXPORT the code as a full solution/project and then compile/debug it.